# How to get entire row value on select of checkbox using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I am using **Typescript**.i have a requirment like in each row one checkbox is there.
On select of checkbox i want the values of entire row(All fields).

For this i am following the below example.

https://plnkr.co/edit/yU4P3zsQ3QaH9Vby8M3I?p=preview

In this they are getting the value of only one field that is **val**

```
  getCheckedValues() {
   return this.eventTypeChkBox.filter(obj => obj.checked).map(obj => obj.val);
  }
```

I want to get the values of all the fields that is **id and chkBoxImageUrl** also.

Can anyone please help me how to do this.I am very new to Typescript.I am not getting exactly how to get this.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/9grbHMBLWcHxaL4vknNM?p=preview

What you were doing wrong was calling `.map(obj => obj.val)` in your `getCheckedValues` method.

Comment: Thank you so much @Leon.I want exactly this one.You saved my day. :)